# Duplicate content issue between two sites having same ‘website navigation steps’ in home page

Tags: seo, google, duplicate-content

My client has two websites `www.example1.com` and `www.example2.com` those websites are same in structure and content.

First site is old one and the second site is fresh site that was registered in this month only (not crawled by Google). I have been working to change the contents of the new one. In the home page of both sites we have ‘How to navigate this website’ section that contains 4 steps to tell our customers about the website and the working methods. Those steps are similar for both sites so I plan to leave that section from checking copyright, which means, I’m going to give same details in both the site. But our home page has some other details like introduction etc and those contents are different so I can’t provide canonical tag in that page. I need Google to consider both the sites as good sites.

What can I do? Is there any attribute to notify Google that both the sections are same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry about it. The pages are so few that Google isn't going to care. Plus the content isn't really something that people search for for you to care how it ranks in search engines. This really is a non-issue and can be considered over-optimization.